# How to locate log files?

Tags: logging, log-files

I'm getting a 500 error on a PHP file. In another question on SE it says to look for log files in `/var/log`. However, I am on shared/paid hosting and that folder is empty. Should I be looking elsewhere instead?

Apache Version 2.2.23

PHP Version 5.4.37

Comment: if this is paid hosting did you ask technical support about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, shared hosting usually logs to the user directory. Search your `$HOME` for `./logs/` or something similar.

However, some hosting providers forbid users to view their logs, in which case you should contact your hosting company's tech. support

Comment: I did find some logs there, but merely logs of visitors, not logs of errors. I will contact my hosting company.